# MS Powerpoint 2007 (Windows) to Microsoft PowerPoint 2004 (Mac)

Tags: macos, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007, office-for-mac

I've a PPT (With some comments on each slides) made with MS Powerpoint 2007 (Windows)

[image]

I saved PPT in **.ppt** extension and sent to my friend who has a Mac and Microsoft PowerPoint 2004. He is unable to see my "comment" . Is there any way so he can see comments?

Answer (score 1):

Wonder if they may have been disabled or hidden.  I googled it and [these](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/use-comments-in-powerpoint-HA001207149.aspx) steps are for Powerpoint 2003 but I think should be portable to 2004.  I have pasted them below in case the link changes.

> View or hide comments
>   As mentioned earlier, when you rest the pointer on the comment, PowerPoint displays the comment box (which resembles a pop-up window) and its contents. When you move the pointer away from the comment, PowerPoint closes the comment box again.
>
> To keep a comment box open after you move the pointer away from the comment, click the comment. PowerPoint displays the comment box until you click another item.
>
> You can turn comments on or off globally by clicking Show Markup or Hide Markup on the Reviewing toolbar.
>
> Review comments
>   When you receive a PowerPoint slide or slide deck from one or more people who have reviewed it and added comments, you'll probably want to review the comments one at a time to address them. PowerPoint makes it easy to step through all of the comments in the slide deck:
>
> 1.Open the slide deck, and if the Reviewing toolbar is not visible, turn it on.
>
> 2.Click Next Item on the Reviewing toolbar.
>
> 3.PowerPoint displays the comment. You can double-click the comment's anchor to keep it open.
>
> To move through the comments, continue clicking Next Item . If you need to move backward through the comments, click Previous Item .

Comment: did these steps helps in the end?